# rate of change of area of circle per second w.r.t. radius

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the rate of change of the area of a circle **per second** with
> respect to its radius when radius=5cm.
>
> [Source](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lemh106.pdf#page=2)

$A= \pi r^2$  ⇒ $\frac{{\rm d}A}{{\rm d}r} =2rπ$

So when $r=5$cm, $\frac{{\rm d}A}{{\rm d}r}= 10 \pi$ cm

But the answer is $10\pi$ cm$^2$/sec. I don't understand how time comes into picture when we are only talking about radius and area? Why is "per second" even mentioned in the question?

Comment: You are correct that this question does not make sense on itself, you need additional information. Probably whoever asked that question imagined a circle growing at a certain speed, i.e. $\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} = v$, and knowing $v$ you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Find the rate of change of the area of a circle **per second** when
>   its radius  of 5 cm  is expanding at  rate of 1 cm **per second**.

... such a question would be better

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the rate of change of the area which is $\frac{dA}{dt}$  and not $\frac{dA}{dr}$.

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\pi r(t)^2)=2\pi r(t) \cdot \frac{dr(t)}{dt} $$

The "dimension" of $\frac{d}{dt}$ is $s^{-1}$ and you will get the correct units, but note that you need to know how the radius changes in time, i.e. $r=r(t)$.

Comment: The question says "rate of change of the area of a circle per second with respect to its radius": it seems like three variables are dependent on each other. How am I even supposed to interpret it? Why it is dA/dt  and not dA/dr

Comment: dA/dr is the rate of change of the area with respect to its radius, that's fine. Either there is something wrong with the question, or we are missing something trivial, but I cannot see how you can get the units cm/s unless you differentiate A with respect to time.

Comment: Sorry i wrote the units wrong.; the answer is 10π cm^2/sec

Comment: yes, yes, that is what I meant, since r has units of cm and dr/dt has units of cm/s, their product has units of cm^2/s.