# How units didn't change while differentiation?

Tags: functions, derivatives, applications, dimensional-analysis, unit-of-measure

[image: This is an example in my textbook in application of derivatives]

In this example, rate of change has units cm², while the original quantity, area, also has same units. I learnt that units change just like normal ratio, that is dA/dr will have same units as A/r, so the units of derivative should have been in cm not cm², right?

So am I missing something here?

Comment: The question is asking for $\frac{dA}{dt}$ which should be in centimeters squared per second. Your book seems to be calculating $\frac{dA}{dr}$ which is $\frac{cm^2}{cm}$, i.e. the change in area with respect to a change in radius. It should have computed $\frac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma But it also says with respect to radius, so how can we say it's asking for dA/dt?

Comment: The wording makes no sense: "rate of change of the area of a circle per second with respect to its radius".  I think the author is confused, or at least neglected to proof-read the manuscript.  Nothing is said about how anything depends on time here, so there is no justification for identifying $dA/dr$ with $dA/dt$.

Comment: This seems to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681374/rate-of-change-of-area-of-circle-per-second-w-r-t-radius. They seem to be referring to the exact same textbook.

Comment: Thank you everyone. So we can conclude that there's something wrong with the question, right?

Comment: Yes, the author and the editors screwed up.